# Excel help - Transpose row values in to columns and repeat adjacent existing row values

Tags: excel

I need help using transpose function in excel. Currently, the values of "GRE" field in my table are spread across columns for each combination of Job category and Annual Salary band. Ideally, the required layout has to contain one row for each combination of Job category, Annual Salary and GRE. Any help is greatly appreciated.`enter code here`

Current Data Before Transpose -

```
enter data format herre
```

Current Result -

```
                    GRE
JC  AnnualSal  A  B  C  D  E  F
1      11      0  0  2  0  0  0
1      12      0  2  9  0  0  1
3      9       1  0  0  3  0  0
```

Expect Result -

```
JC  AnnualSal  GRE  Count
1       11      C     2
1       12      B     2
1       12      C     9
1       12      F     1
3        9      A     1
3        9      D     3
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLmC2.png)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

1. Select cells A2:H5
2. Select the Data Menu, then From Table / Range

[image]

[image]

3. Click OK

[image]

4. Power Query Editor will open

[image]

5. Select Columns A:F
6. Select the Transform Menu
7. Select Unpivot Columns, Unpivot Columns

[image]

[image]

8. Rename `Attribute` to `GRE`
9. Rename `Value` to `Count`
10. Select the Dropdown Arrow in the `Count` column and **uncheck 0**

[image]

11. Select the Home Menu, then Close & Close, Close & Load To...

[image]

[image]

12. Click OK

[image]

Comment: Nice explanation, but no need to `Insert/Table`.  `Data\From Table/Range` will convert a range to a table if it is not.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation, This is so very helpful. However, I do not see Table/ Range under Data menu which I believe is required to launch power query editor. I checked add ins under options and can't find an option for power query editor even there. I'm using Excel 2013 and it is my understanding features listed above are compatible.

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/powerpivot-for-excel-2013-is-missing-from-com-add/dbd42ed4-ca44-4fdd-b090-55b4b495275 or https://kb.iu.edu/d/bcuz might help